# The Ghost Coins led me to a blank wall, how do I open it?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

After the Defence Against the Dark Arts classroom, which restored my years 1-4 spells, the ghost coins led me to a blue arrow pointing in front of a blank wall, with a lion's head above it.

I am guessing I need to open it, but pulling the torches doesn't do the trick?  How do I get the wall to open?

Comment: Stephen - while it is perfectly OK to answer your own question, it is polite to give other people some time (a few hours or a day) to provide answers first.  Otherwise it just looks like you are seeding the site and/or farming for reputation.

Comment: @JasonBerkan Thanks Jason, I wasn't sure what way to go since these questions are related to a Gaming Grant that was awarded and I wasn't sure how long to hold off on the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the left of the wall there is a student with a ladle looking object above his head.

Go down the stairs and look for a student carrying the ladle.  Zap him 3-4 times with your attack spell and he will drop it.  Bring the item back to the first student and the wall will explode.